# IDictionaryFactory is not supported on this platform when using AutoMapper

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, automapper, asp.net-mvc-5

I've installed AutoMapper 3.1.0-ci1027 via NuGet into an MVC5 website. I've used [Owain Wraggs' Blog](http://consultingblogs.emc.com/owainwragg/archive/2010/12/15/automapper-profiles.aspx) as my guide to help me out.

My config file looks like this:

```
public static class AutoMapperConfig
{
    public static void Initialize()
    {
        Mapper.Initialize(x =>
        {
            x.AddProfile<DomainToViewModelMappers>();
            x.AddProfile<ViewModelToDomainMappers>();
        });
    }
}
```

I am calling the Initialize() method from within Global.asax.cs.Application_Start():

```
AutoMapperConfig.Initialize();
```

However, when I run the application it crashes at Mapper.Initialize(). This will happen even if I don't include any code in there. The code runs fine if I comment this line out, but of course, then I'm not using AutoMapper to connect my objects.

The errors I am seeing are as follows:

> [PlatformNotSupportedException: This type is not supported on this
>   platform IDictionaryFactory]
>   AutoMapper.Internal.PlatformAdapter.Resolve(Boolean throwIfNotFound)
>   +320    AutoMapper.TypeMapFactory..cctor() +46
>
> [TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for
>   'AutoMapper.TypeMapFactory' threw an exception.]
>   AutoMapper.TypeMapFactory..ctor() +0
>   AutoMapper.Mapper.<.cctor>b__0() +55
>   AutoMapper.Internal.LazyImpl`1.get_Value() +79
>
>   AutoMapper.Mapper.get_ConfigurationProvider() +34
>
>   AutoMapper.Mapper.get_Configuration() +28
>
>   AutoMapper.Mapper.Initialize(Action`1 action) +51
>   AIMS.Mappers.AutoMapperConfig.Initialize() in
>   c:\Projects\AIMS\AIMS\Mappers\AutoMapperConfig.cs:9
>   AIMS.MvcApplication.Application_Start() in
>   c:\Projects\AIMS\AIMS\Global.asax.cs:25
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): The type initializer for
>   'AutoMapper.TypeMapFactory' threw an exception.]
>   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.EnsureAppStartCalledForIntegratedMode(HttpContext
>   context, HttpApplication app) +9936841
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr
>   appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +118
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state,
>   MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +172
>   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr
>   appContext, HttpContext context) +336
>   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr
>   appContext) +296
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): The type initializer for
>   'AutoMapper.TypeMapFactory' threw an exception.]
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +9915380 
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context)
>   +101    System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest
>   wr, HttpContext context) +254

Any thoughts on what I'm missing would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What does your project structure look like?

Comment: Nevermind, I just got this as well. Will be fixed shortly...

Comment: Thank you. I'm new to AutoMapper, so I just figured I was missing something silly in my own instantiation. Any rate, I've started reading your blog. I'm finding a lot of good tips in there.

Comment: Did you find a fix for this? I'm getting this as well.

Comment: Not yet. I believe we're waiting on an AutoMapper patch. You might consider rolling AutoMapper back to a previous version... I haven't tried that yet.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This was a bug in AutoMapper, the version 3.1.0-ci1032 contains the fix. Turns out supporting portable class libraries took a bit more work :)

Comment: Appreciate the fix, that one got me to.  If I may humbly suggest, you might want to roll out a new stable version soon - that's gonna keep poping up..

Comment: Using nuget to update automapper worked for me: install-package automapper